# Follow up to phone formatting: More than 1 phone number field.

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question regarding the phone number formatting code in Swift 3 / Xcode. Vikzilla supplied excellent code for formatting. However, I have 2 phone fields in my app. One is phone number, the other is fax number. As mentioned, the answer supplied by Vikzilla is perfect but I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to edit in this code for the second field (fax number) without either throwing " invalid redeclaration of 'textfield..." error. I have renamed the 2nd function etc. no errors are thrown but the formatting of the fax field doesn't work... Help? Below is the code. As I mentioned it works perfect but I am not sure how to edit it so it will work on the 2nd. field (faxNumber). Thanks!

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (textField == self.phoneField){
        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let components = newString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)

        let decimalString = components.joined(separator: "") as NSString
        let length = decimalString.length
        let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.character(at: 0) == (1 as unichar)

        if length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 11 {
            let newLength = (textField.text! as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

            return (newLength > 10) ? false : true
        }
        var index = 0 as Int
        let formattedString = NSMutableString()

        if hasLeadingOne {
            formattedString.append("1 ")
            index += 1
        }
        if (length - index) > 3 {
            let areaCode = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("(%@)", areaCode)
            index += 3
        }
        if length - index > 3 {
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
            index += 3
        }

        let remainder = decimalString.substring(from: index)
        formattedString.append(remainder)
        textField.text = formattedString as String
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your phone formatting hardcoded to handle only phone numbers from the USA and Canada? Don't you wish to support other countries?

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the one `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method. Simply remove the initial `if` (and its `else`). Then your code will work for both text fields.

If you actually have more than just the two phone number text fields then simply update the `if` to be:

```
if (textField == self.phoneField || textField == self.faxField) {
```

As a side note, your code will only work for phone numbers in the USA and Canada, not any other countries.

Comment: Perfect solution! I will research a solution for international numbers as well. Thanks very much for your help. I can't believe it was so simple. I am a bit of a newbie.